# Remove 0 at beginning of formatted time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I have an `NSDate` formatted with `NSDateFormatter` as "hh:mm:ss". Everything displays properly except when the hour is one digit (e.g. 3:00) it would display 03:00. How would I get rid of that 0 so it would display 3:00?

Comment: What other date formats have you tried using?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use 1 `h` instead of two you will not get the leading 0.

`h:mm:ss`